# Temporarily escape function scope to define global symbols in C? (gcc)

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, gnu-assembler

Is there any way, in standard C or failing that with gcc/gas/binutils/etc, to define a global symbol using code (probably a macro) that's written within the syntatical scope of a function definition body?

**Without** the need for a separate macro for each such symbol appearing outside the function body?

For this purpose it's fine if I have to explicitly specify the ELF section to put the generated symbol in, fine if I have to use asm features like `.pushsection` and `.popsection` (if they can help?) etc. Any and all gcc extensions are fair game.

The reason I want do do this crazy thing is so that a tracepoint declaration (which must appear in a function body) can autogenerate associated metadata the tracing tool can look up. Without the need to separately pre-declare the tracepoints, i.e. make it as DRY as possible.

### Pesudocode

```
void foo(void)
{
    normal_app_code();
    MAGICALLY_DEFINE_A_GLOBAL_VARIABLE_SYMBOL(symboltype, symbolname);
    more_normal_app_code();
}
```

such that the result of compilation is as if the above had been written:

```
symboltype symbolname;

void foo(void)
{
    normal_app_code();
    some_library_function_that_uses(symbolname);
    more_normal_app_code();
}
```

---

### Context

I'm working on an idea for enhancing the systemtap/dtrace tracing API to support recording data types and names for probe arguments.

The design I have currently requires application authors to insert additional macros in top-level (global) scope to define the symbols that the stap runtime will use to discover the names and arg types of the probes, e.g. the contrived:

```
STAP_PROBE2_ARGNAMES(myprovider, myprobe, foo, bar);
STAP_PROBE2_ARGTYPES(myprovider, myprobe, const char *, MyDataType*);

void something(const char *foo)
{
    MyDataType *bar = get_bar();
    STAP_PROBE2(myprovider, myprobe, foo, bar);
}
```

That's inconvenient and it's going to be error-prone. Especially if the app wants to autogenerate `STAP_PROBEn(..)` probe points as part of its own macros.

I'd rather declare the arg type and name info alongside the tracepoint, at the  same site, using preprocessor stringification to capture arg names (when they're simple variable name tokens) and the `__typeof__` operator to capture their type names, something like:

```
void something(const char *foo)
{
    MyDataType *bar = get_bar();
    STAP_PROBE2_ARGINFO(myprovider, myprobe, foo, bar);
}
```

or for non-simple-token expression arguments something like:

```
void something(void)
{
    MyDataTypeHolder *barholder = get_barholder();
    STAP_PROBE2_ARGNAMES(myprovider, myprobe,
        something_global->foo, "foo",
        barholder->bar, "bar");
}
```

The macro expansion of `STAP_PROBE2_ARGINFO` takes care of generating a separate pair of symbols for char-array-arrays in the global symbol table using appropriate stringification and using the `_typeof_` operator, e.g. the pseudo-ish-c:

```
#define STAP_PROBE2_ARGINFO(myprovider, myprobe, arg1, arg2) \
    STAP_PROBE2(myprovider, myprobe, (arg1), (arg2)) \
    STAP_PROBE2_ARGTYPES(myprovider, myprobe, (arg1), (arg2))
    STAP_PROBE2_ARGNAMES(myprovider, myprobe, (arg1), (arg2))

#define STAP_PROBE2_ARGTYPES(myprovider, myprobe, argname1, argname2) \
    const char _stapargtypes_#myprovider#_#myprobe[2][] = {#argname1, #argname2};

#define STAP_PROBE2_ARGTYPES(myprovider, myprobe, arg1, arg2) \
    const char _stapargtypes_#myprovider#_#myprobe[2][] = {__typeof__((arg1)), __typeof__((arg2))};
```

... and something similar for `STAP_PROBE2_ARGNAMES` that extracts and stores the explicitly supplied arg names separately.

The goal is that the result would resemble global declarations of:

```
const char _stapargnames_myprovider_myprobe[2][] = {"foo", "bar"};
const char _stapargtypes_myprovider_myprobe[2][] = {"const char *", "MyDataType*"};
```

and also emit the usual asm for the probe point itself at the callsite where the `STAP_PROBE2_ARGINFO(...)` appeared, as if it was a normal `STAP_PROBE2(...)`.

Crazy?

Possible?

Comment: I found the gas/binutils `.pushsection` and `.popsection` directives but they don't seem especially documented, and it's not clear if they can help here.

Comment: I'm also considering emitting a symbol for each trace argument that's an uninitialized and unused dummy of `__typeof__(the_arg)`, named appropriately so stap can find it at runtime. This might be very handy since we can then ask for the DWARF type debuginfo of that symbol to get the type of the arg. Unsure yet if it's needed or if just having the type name is enough but I suspect it'd help when there are layers of macros etc at work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you can't do this with `__asm__` and `.pushsection`. Make an `extern` declaration for the variable in C, which is valid in block scope, so that it's accessible from the C, and pass its size as an integer literal operand to the `__asm__`. The inside the `__asm__`, you can define the symbol, make it `.global` if you wish (or not), and reserve space for it based on the passed-in size.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used any inline asm before so this is new territory for me. I appreciate the guidance. I wasn't aware that an extern was valid in block scope, that's very useful for this. Much appreciated. I can use the existing <sys/sdt.h> for some guidance on the asm.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that could work ( though slightly differently ) would be

Major sudo code... but it will give you the idea

```
declare 2 global vars
unsigned char* my_stack;
unsigned long int stack_size=0;


my_function
{
    normal code....

    if(my_stack==NULL)
    {
        my_stack=malloc(size of vars you need to store);
        stack_size=new_size;
    }
    else { my_stack=realloc(my_stack, stack_size + new_vars_size ); }

    my_stack[stack_size+1]=  <-- start pushing your new vars on the stack here

    more normal code....
}
```

It's global and you can do it in real time on the fly. You could even make it into a function to make it simple and easy. That is a super simple example, but you could make it hold the name of the var, the type of the var and the value. You could also use a structure to make it easier to use... whatever you want. That just illustrates the idea.

In hind sight... a linked list of objects would probably be the best way to this.

something like(more sudo code):

```
struct my_var
{
    char name[50];
    int type;
    unsigned char *data;
}

struct my_stack
{
    my_var* previous;
    my_var* current;
    my_var* next;
}
```

Comment: Kind of you to suggest, but not suitable for what I'm doing. (Not my downvote though). I can't be doing runtime allocations etc, tracepoints might be in extremely hot paths and should be side-effect free.